# Xamarin for android Visual studio 2017 RC deploy app with empty layout

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Xamarin for android Visual studio 2017 RC deploy empty app while I have made a lot of change in layout, this I driving me crazy, I can't solve this error by my own, PLEASE HELP ME T SOLVE THIS PROBLEM. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Activity's `OnCreate` Method after `base.OnCreate(bundle)`:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```